# Controlling button on YwRobot with Raspberry Pi

Tags: wiring, breadboard

I am obviously new to Raspberry and Stack, but would be great if community can advice.

**My setup is the following**:
 - `YwRobot 545043` power supply (controller) connected to the breadboard and to the Raspberry, which powers it (the controller)
 - the USB input from YwRobot is connected to LED lamps; once button on controller is switched on, LED are lighted up

**What I want to do**
Connect the button on `YwRobot` to the Raspberry board somehow, so that when it is pressed, I receive input/output into the Raspberry

**Use case is:**
Designing an alarm that through `while` loop will check current time, and when condition is met, it will turn the leds on; when button on controller or breadboard is pressed -- turns them off.

**What I cannot figure:**
Is there a way to associate this YwRobots physical button with, say another button on breadboard that can send actual state of the buttoon back to Raspberry.

Essentially I need to link `button 1` to Raspberry or to `button 2`

Here is an image below
[image]

Much appreciate any ideas!

Comment: `Here is a schema below`  .... no, it is not a schematic .... it is a picture of wires

Comment: Indeed, sorry. The actual wiring is perhaps not that important, mostly to understand what I want to achieve

Comment: As a last resort resort, you _could_, of course, cut the LED lamp's USB cord and wire the red and black wires within, through a transistor, to the pi's 5v power supply... Then you could read the button button using the GPIO pins and control the transistor using the GPIO pins.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate power supply for the raspberry pi and connect the 3.3V power to a GPIO. Then, you could have a python program read the GPIO to see whether the button (1) was pressed.

Like:

Power->Raspberry Pi<-YwRobot 545043 power supply

Or:

YwRobot 545043 power supply->Button 2->GPIO

Comment: Thanks! The issue is I am not sure exactly how to wire Yw_Robot to the breadbboard itself. It has pins close to the button, but they don't seem to be configurable to read the input from the button

Comment: On most power supplies like yours, button 1 is used for turning on or off the power supply. The green led indicates whether the power supply is on.

Comment: Yes, it is, but the goal here is to connect the button on the power supply to the Raspberry, since I want to control USB output programatically.

Comment: Yes so follow my post